# How to get anchor tag onClick ?

Tags: anchor

I am trying to submit closest form from anchor tag.Page has multiple forms, each with anchor to submit respective form. My event target and this both return the URL value.
How could i get my anchor element so that i could reference my closest form.

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="RolesIndex" value="XXX">    
    <a class="linktext" href="#">Submit</a>
</form>
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="RolesIndex" value="XXX2">    
    <a class="linktext" href="#">Submit2</a>
</form>
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.linktext').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert(this);            
            alert(event.target);
        });
    });
```

Result i get from my alert 
http://localhost/WebApplication1/Home/Index#

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to achieve my goal.

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="RolesIndex" value="XXX">
    <a onclick="SubmitForm(this);" href="javascript:void(0);">Submit</a>
</form>
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="RolesIndex" value="XXX2">
    <a onclick="SubmitForm(this);" href="javascript:void(0);">Submit</a>
</form>


<script>        
    function SubmitForm(el) {
        jQuery(el).closest('form').submit();
    }
</script>
```